# player opening more than one time?

Tags: php, html, xml

[This is my site.](http://www.musicking.in) When i will select songs for playing player.php file will open and it will play the songs selected.

Everything working fine,but the problem is when o will go back and select another songs it is opening one more player window. please help me.

I want only one player window has to be opened even i select other songs also.
to check the problem go to [this url](http://musicking.in/ilayaraja-hitstelugu.html) and play the songs once

player.php

```
createElement("playlist");
$dom->appendChild($root);
$root->setAttribute('version', "1");
$root->setAttribute('xmlns', "http://xspf.org/ns/0/");
$rootnext = $dom->createElement("trackList");
$root->appendChild($rootnext);
foreach ($song as $counter) {
    $tokens = ",";
    $tokenized = strtok($counter, $tokens);
// create child element

$song = $dom->createElement("track");
$rootnext->appendChild($song);
$song1 = $dom->createElement("creator");
$song->appendChild($song1);
$text = $dom->createTextNode("www.musicking.in");
$song1->appendChild($text); 
$song1 = $dom->createElement("title");
$song->appendChild($song1);
// create text node
$text = $dom->createTextNode($tokenized);
$song1->appendChild($text); 
$tokenized = strtok($tokens);
$song1 = $dom->createElement("location");
$song->appendChild($song1);
$text = $dom->createTextNode($tokenized);
$song1->appendChild($text); 

}
// save 
$dom->save("playlist.xml");
?>
```

playlist.xml

```
www.musicking.inDuryodhana's dialouge1/Ntr dialouges/duryodhana's dialouge.mp3www.musicking.inDuryodhana's dialouge2/Ntr dialouges/dvsk_dialogues-10.mp3www.musicking.inDuryodhana's dialouge3/Ntr dialouges/dvsk_dialogues-3.mp3www.musicking.inDuryodhana's dialouge4/Ntr dialouges/dvsk_dialogues-4.mp3www.musicking.inDuryodhana's dialouge5/Ntr dialouges/dvsk_dialogues-5.mp3www.musicking.inDuryodhana's dialouge6/Ntr dialouges/dvsk_dialogues-6.mp3www.musicking.inDuryodhana's dialouge7/Ntr dialouges/dvsk_dialogues-7.mp3www.musicking.inDuryodhana's dialouge8/Ntr dialouges/dvsk_dialogues-8.mp3www.musicking.inDuryodhana's dialouge9/Ntr dialouges/dvsk_dialogues-9.mp3www.musicking.inDuryodhana's dialouge10/Ntr dialouges/dvsk_dialogues-11.mp3www.musicking.inDuryodhana's dialouge11/Ntr dialouges/karna's dialouge.mp3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alekc has it right.

Your form code is this:

```
<form method="post" action="/player.php" target="_blank">
```

You should change the target to something like `player`.  This change will still cause the player to open in a new window, but that window will be uniquely named.

```
<form method="post" action="/player.php" target="player">
```

Then, when a user clicks on "Play Selected," instead of opening another window, it will load into the old player.

Answer (score 4):

I think that it opens a new window because you have specified target='_blank' in the form. Try to use different target (i.e. target="player").

Answer (score 1):

if i will put a player in the same window player will stop playing songs when user go to other page for othe songs
.
so my player should be open in other window.

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with Alekc.

For a better user experience you should also not open a new window but put the player div inside the page in iframe and then simple change the src of the iframe (easy with javascript or jquery) to your new playlist. Most of web users have popup blocking scripts, so the player may even not display.

Putting the player inside the page improves your design and usability.

Comment: if i will put a player in the same window player will stop playing songs when user go to other page for othe songs . so my player should be open in other window.